# jQuery :contains selector does not work with jQueryUI slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, filter, contains

I have the following code.

```
<ul>
    <li class="prod" data-channels="3 4 6 8">product 1</li>
    <li class="prod" data-channels="1">product 2</li>
    <li class="prod" data-channels="2 8">product 3</li>
    <li class="prod" data-channels="3 8">product 4</li>
    <li class="prod" data-channels="3">product 5</li>
    <li class="prod" data-channels="6">product 6</li>
</ul>

$("#slider").slider({
    value: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 24,  
    step: 1,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $("#amount").val(ui.value);
        var filter = ui.value;

        if (filter) {
            $('li.prod').each(function (index) {
                var channels = $(this).data('channels');
                if (channels == filter) {
                    $(this).fadeTo("fast", 1);
                } 
                else {
                    $(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.3);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
$("#amount").val($("#slider").slider("value"));
```

What I am trying to do is get it to `fadeto` the products that contain certain values in the data `channels` tag. It works fine when the data-channels had single values. But now the client wants it to have multiple values like below.

So I can't use the `==` operator I need to do some sort of contains operator, something like the below but I have hit a brick wall.

```
var channels = $(this).data('channels');
if ($("li.prod:contains('"+channels+"')")) {
    $(this).fadeTo("fast", 1);
} 
else {
    $(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.3);
}
```

But it's not working properly. Here's a jsfiddle that contains my code: http://jsfiddle.net/isimpledesign/CmJXm/3/

Comment: You do realize that `:contains` operates on the *contents* of the element, not the `data-*` attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just split the *channels* string var into single values (separator is *space*) and test each value ?

Comment: Thank you so much just checked back to this post for answer and your worked perfect ;)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're asking, you can do it with the 'attribute word selector'.

Like so:

```
$("li.prod[data-channels~='"+channel+"'").each(function (index) {
    $(this).fadeTo("fast", 1);
});
```

In other words, to select index 0, 2, 3 from your example:

```
$("li.prod[data-channels~='8'")
```

If you want to fade the rest of them to `.3`, I'd mark the matching channels then select all those who don't have the mark. Like so:

**Updated**

So, for your exact problem, to show/hide when it's data-channel contains the slider's current value, bind this to its slide event:

```
function (event, ui) {
    ...
    // reset marker        
    $("li.prod").attr("data-active", "false");

    // show channels
    $("li.prod[data-channels~='"+ui.value+"'").each(function (index) {
        $(this).fadeTo("fast", 1);
        $(this).attr("data-active", "true"); // mark them
    });

    // hide rest
    $("li.prod[data-active!='true'").each(function (index) {
        $(this).fadeTo("fast", .3);
    });
}
```

**Updated (x2)**

Thanks to @YiJiang feedback we don't have to do all that marker stuff. Just use the `siblings` selector to chain in the channels you want to hide. Like so:

```
function (event, ui) {
    ...

    // show target channels
    $("li.prod[data-channels~='"+ui.value+"'").fadeTo("fast", 1)
        .siblings().fadeTo("fast", .3);

}
```

Comment: hi Deeno trying to get this to work here is a better example of what i am trying to achieve  jsfiddle.net/isimpledesign/CmJXm/8

Comment: That example is actually really confusing. I'm still not sure what you're asking. Can you simplify it more? Seems like there's a few steps in there.

Comment: hi deeno yeah sorry quite hard to example if you take this example http://jsfiddle.net/isimpledesign/CmJXm/1/ you can see them fading in for the lists with the data-channel = to the slider channel so on the first li element its has 3 4 6 8 i want it to be fadeTo 1 on all these values. thanks

Comment: Why not just use `$("li.prod[data-channels~='"+ui.value+"'").fadeTo("fast", 1).siblings().fadeTo("fast", .3);`?

Comment: @YiJiang uhh, because that would be too easy... :) Totally forgot about siblings. Great idea! Updated.

Answer (score 0):

`split()` and `indexOf()` can solve your problem. Change the following line of your original code:

```
if (channels == filter) {
```

To:

```
if (channels.toString().split( ' ' ).indexOf( filter.toString() ) > -1 ) {
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/QSYz8/